# Making it seem like a dropdown box is chosen - Excel

Tags: excel

in the example I have four columns that the User can fill data in (B-E), but the number of columns changes based on the dropdown lists - it's always a minimum of 3 and a maximum of 4.  I have a script that I run to populate hundreds of columns (G and on) based on the last dropdown chosen using a control column, F.  So if someone picks Foundation in Column D I know that's the last column to be chosen and I make Column F Foundation.  In the case of Sump Pump, I know it's four columns so I check column D for Sump Pump and put that in Column F.  But simply having a formula that copies the data doesn't make it seem like a dropdown has been 'chosen' and my VBA script doesn't fire.  If I take the formula out of Column F (which I can't) and make it a dropdown box in Column F and I pick something from the dropdown box the VBA formula fires great.  How do I 'make it seem like Column F was a chosen dropdown box'?  Thanks!
[image]

Comment: @Evil Blue Monkey I reposted it here but the column to handle the effort (Column F) is not doing the job

Comment: @Evil Blue Monkey how can we trigger using new placeholder column?